# when mouse over image slide is start as gif image

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I have 5 images in a same folder.
1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg,5.jpg
I will be show only one image on my webpage.
example

```
<body>
<img src="1.jpg">
</body>
```

when visitor is mouse over on image, image will be change to 2.jpg and,3.jpg and....will be stop at 5.jpg.Slideshow is similar as a gif image.
Please How to write javascript or jquery .
Please tell me simplest way.
Thank my dear friend.
I found simalor question in this website.But I can't found complete answer for me.
If this question is duplicate, so sorry
please forgive me for my poor english useage.

Comment: Please improve the text. I can't understand what you want\need.

Comment: Also, please show what you've tried.

Comment: than for your comment my friends.I will show example link.http://www.clipsharedemo.com/ go to this website.See Turkish Nice Song photo.When you mouse over, images will be change. I mean it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's hover event and pass in the `onenter` and `onout` methods. On enter you can call and setup an interval to increment the number of your image, and on out you want to stop it by clearing your interval.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>image</title>        
  </head>
  <body>

    <img id="img" src="1.jpg" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var interval = null;
      function changeImage(){
        var nextNum = parseInt($('#img').attr('src').replace('.jpg',''), 10) + 1;
        // If you want it to repeat back to 1 after 5
        nextNum = nextNum > 5 ? 1 : nextNum;
        $('#img').attr('src', nextNum+'.jpg');
      }

      $('#img').hover(
        function(){
          // Call change Image every 50ms
          interval = setInterval(changeImage, 50);
          changeImage();
        },
        function(){
          // Stop the call
          interval && clearInterval(interval);
        }
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: hello my dear friend,I tried as you say.When mouse over image is not change.My complete code is 'code'<html>
<head><title>image</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#img').mouseenter(function(){
    var nextNum = parseInt($(this).attr('src').replace('.jpg',''), 10) + 1;
    // If you want to go back to one after 5
    nextNum = nextNum > 5 ? 1 : nextNum;
    $(this).attr('src', nextNum+'.jpg');
})?

</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="img" src="1.jpg" />

</body>

</html> 'code'

Comment: Hi, put the two `<script>` tags (jquery and the mouseenter) at the bottom of your page, right before the `</body>`

Comment: Please Can you show me complete file?I am not success until now :(.I tried again and again.I am new to jquery.Thank for your answer and your patient.

Comment: Sure, I've changed my answer above to include the full document.

Comment: when I mouse over on image,1.jpg is  change to 2.jpg and stop.Next I mouse over 2.jpg ,image is change to 3.jpg.I need is one mouse over,images is will be change 2.jpg ,3.jpg,...,5.jpg continuesly.Please.See it demo link.[link]http://www.clipsharedemo.com

Comment: I see, I've updated the answer so it would loop continuously until you hover off the image and explained it as well.

Comment: Now, everything is ok.Mr.Rgthree ,I don't know how to thank.May be happy my dear friend.