# how to insert variable value in query?

Tags: jquery

I want to edit following code.(This code is come from [http://stackoverflow.com/a/9280414/945688]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>image</title>        
  </head>
  <body>

    <img id="img" src="1.jpg" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var interval = null;
      function changeImage(){
        var nextNum = parseInt($('#img').attr('src').replace('.jpg',''), 10) + 1;
        // If you want it to repeat back to 1 after 5
        nextNum = nextNum > 5 ? 1 : nextNum;
        $('#img').attr('src', nextNum+'.jpg');
      }

      $('#img').hover(
        function(){
          // Call change Image every 50ms
          interval = setInterval(changeImage, 50);
          changeImage();
        },
        function(){
          // Stop the call
          interval && clearInterval(interval);
        }
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

The above code is fine work.But I want to substitute in image path.

If

```
    <?php $image_folder_path='imagenewfolder';?>
<img id="img" src="images/<?php echo $image_fold_path; ?>/1.jpg>
```

,How to edit jquery code .

Comment: i dont get your question, can you please help a little more?

Comment: See this link.[link]http://stackoverflow.com/a/9280414/945688.I want to change jquery code variable value with php.

Comment: which value do you want to change?

Comment: I want to change image path.Original image path is <img src='1.jpg>.I want to change php variable. <img src='images/<?php echo $imagefolder; ?>/1.jpg.But I don't know how to edit in jquery.

Comment: oh i think i get it, you mean your current naming scheme is 1.jpg,2.jpg etc, and you want to replace it with somefoldername/1.jpg, somefoldername/2.jpg? and your current jquery code is not working with this, if so will foldername be constant?

Comment: foldername is not beconstant.Foldername is varialbe.So I will substitute with php.example.<img src="images/<?php echo $imagesubfolder ;?>/1.jpg>.Each subfolder have 1.jpg ,2.jpg...and 20.jpg.

Comment: no i mean for one series will folder names be same for all images for example if you loaded one image from somefoldername, will all the images on "that" page will be loaded from somefoldername?

Comment: Images is will be show in same folder name.Image path is same for all images.

Comment: then its easy, wait lemme post an answer

Comment: OK,Thank my dear friend.Pleae give me full complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code.

```
var interval = null;
var imgPath = '<?php echo $image_path; ?>'; // it should have a trailing slash
      function changeImage(){
        var nextNum = parseInt($('#img').attr('src').replace(imgPath,'').replace('.jpg',''), 10) + 1;
        // If you want it to repeat back to 1 after 5
        nextNum = nextNum > 5 ? 1 : nextNum;
        $('#img').attr('src', imgPath + nextNum+'.jpg');
      }

      $('#img').hover(
        function(){
          // Call change Image every 50ms
          interval = setInterval(changeImage, 50);
          changeImage();
        },
        function(){
          // Stop the call
          interval && clearInterval(interval);
        }
      );
```